# reading from file and putting in a container c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project where I must implement a heterogeneous list of queues and stacks. I implement the list, but when I try to put information in it somethings goes wrong. I must read information from a file and put this info in a list; the list consists of n containers. Each row in the file (which is something like `stack 1 2 4 5`) is a container in the heterogeneous list, where the first string shows if the container is a stack or a queue. I try to read info and put it in a list, but it reads only the first row.

Here is my code:

```
void write_in_txt(int n){
ofstream foo("conteiners.txt");
string type;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  cin>>type;
  foo << type;
  int num = 1;
   while(num != 0){
      cin>>num;
   if(num!=0){
      foo<<" ";
      foo<<num; }
    }
  foo << endl;
  }
}

void read_and_make(int n,QueueStackList& qsl){
  ifstream data("conteiners.txt");
  string tmp;
  LinkedListIterator<Object<int>*> it;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(i == 0){
     int temp;
     data >> tmp;
     if(tmp.compare("stack")){
       qsl.insertEnd(new StackObject<int>);
       it = qsl.begin();
       while(data >> temp){
         (*it)->insert(temp);
       }
     }
    else
        {
        qsl.insertEnd(new QueueObject<int>);
        it = qsl.begin();
        while(data >> temp){
            (*it)->insert(temp);
        }
    }
   }
   else {
        int temp;
     data >> tmp;
     if(tmp.compare("stack")){
       qsl.insertEnd(new StackObject<int>);
       it++;
       while(data >> temp){
         (*it)->insert(temp);
       }
     }
    else
        {
        qsl.insertEnd(new QueueObject<int>);
        it++;
        while(data >> temp){
            (*it)->insert(temp);
        }
    }

   }
  }
}
```

containers.txt:

```
stack 4 7 4 7 7
stack 9 8 7 4
queue 1 2 5 3
stack 8 7 7 7
```

and main-function:

```
int main(){
QueueStackList qsl;
//write_in_txt(4);
read_and_make(4, qsl);

cout << qsl <<endl;   ///prints only 4 7 4 7 7
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You would have simpler code if you created you stack or queue first, populated with data, then inserted into the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while(data >> temp){
  ...
}
```

This operation will not stop at the end of the line, but continue to the next line and try to read "stack" into an *integer* variable, which puts `data` into a `fail` state.

There are several ways to address this problem. You could alter the format of `containers.txt` and add a leading number indicating how many numbers are in the line. Or you could read the entire line with `getline`, and then parse it (either "by hand" or with stringstream). Or you could attempt to clear the `fail` state, recover the word "stack" and proceed (I'm not sure how to do this).